# Fondo de la barra de navegacion de pagina web

Tags: html, css, html5

Tengo una lista de navegacion en la cual quiero que el color de fondo ocupe mas lugar pero no lo logro.
Intente utilizar witdh en .clase1 .clase2 .clase3 y tambien en nav pero no logro que el fondo se agrande y ocupe mas lugar. Necesito que el fondo empieze desde el principio del lado izquierdo de la pagina y termine en la section que se ubica a la derecha de la lista de navegacion

Mi codigo html es el siguente:

```css
header{
    background-color:#900c37;
        border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu {
       position: fixed;
       top: 10;
       margin-left: 10px;
}

ol li{
    display:table;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 1px
    
}

section {
        margin-left: 200px;
      }



h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
}

.clase1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,186,3,0), rgba(252, 186, 3, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
  
.clase2{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(209,64,36,0), rgba(209, 64, 36, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.clase3{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(156,9,26,0), rgba(156, 9, 26, 1));
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

img{
        
        display: block;'
        width: 130px;
        height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ejericio 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>Gestion de Series</h1>
        </header>
        <nav class="menu"><ol>
              <li><a href ="#Series" class="clase1"> Series</a></li>
              <li><a href ="#Opiniones" class="clase2"> Opiniones</a></li>
              <li><a href ="#Estadistica" class="clase3"> Estadisticas</a></li>
              </ol>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
           <article class="manejo-de-series">
              <h2 id="Series">Manejo de Series</h2>
              <p>
              Nombre
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Nombre">
              <br>
              Descripcion
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Descripcion">
              <br>
              Cantidad de temporadas
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto">
              <br>
              Capitulos por temporada
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto">
              </p>
              <p>
              <button type="button"> Agregar/Actualizar </button>
              <button type="button"> Reset </button>
              <button type="button"> Previo </button>
              <button type="button"> Siguiente </button>
              </p>
              <p>
              <a href="https://www.imdb.com/" target="_blank">  <img src="imagenes/IMDb.png" alt="IMDb"> </a>
              </p>
           </article>
           </section>
```

Agradezco ayuda para poder solucionar mi problema.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

1.- Lo que yo te recomendaría es que agregues un div que envuelva a estos dos elementos `nav` y `section` para que puedas manipularlos de una manera mas fácil, quedando tu estructura de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="container-nav">
        <nav class="menu">
         
        </nav>
        
        <section>
          
        </section>
  </div>
```

2.- Nota que hemos agregado un div con la clase `container-nav,` este envuelve a tu `nav` y a tu `section`

3.- Una vez hecho lo anterior, le damos un `display flex` a tu `container-nav` ahora es una caja flexible y los elementos que hay dentro podemos manipularlos con mas facilidad, estos son algunos estilos que le hemos dado a este div:

```
.container-nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 550px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

4.- Ahora vamos con el elemento que tiene la clase `menu`, de primera mano le quitamos la propiedad `position: fixed;` y se la cambiamos por `position: relative;` y yo le quitaria el margen superior e izquierdo tambien. Quedando tus estilos de la siguiente manera:

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
}
```

5.- Ahora vamos con los estilos de tu `li` de primera mano yo le quitaria el `display: table;` y los margenes que has agregado, quedando tus estilos de esta manera:

```
ol li {
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

6.- Ahora vamos con tu `section,` de igual forma quitamos los margenes que has agregado quedando tus estilos de la siguiente manera:

```
section {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
}
```

7.- Ahora vamos con la parte **responsive** de este menu, y aqui la importancia de utilizar `flex-box` lo unico que vamos a hacer es que cuando la pantalla sea pequeña, vamos a cambiarle la direccion a nuestro `container-nav` quedando los estilos de la siguiente manera:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

8.- **TE DEJO UNA GUIA PARA QUE PUEDAS COMPRENDER LAS PROPIEDADES DE FLEX-BOX QUE UTILIZAMOS EN ESTE EJERCICIO**

[Conceptos Básicos de flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

[Usando las cajas flexibles CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS)

9.- Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría tu menu aplicando lo anterior.

```css
header {
  background-color: #900c37;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-nav {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  width: 98%;
  max-width: 550px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  background: coral;
  position: relative;
  flex: auto;
}

ol li {
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
}

section {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.clase1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255, 186, 3, 0),
    rgba(252, 186, 3, 1)
  );
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.clase2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(209, 64, 36, 0),
    rgba(209, 64, 36, 1)
  );
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.clase3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(156, 9, 26, 0),
    rgba(156, 9, 26, 1)
  );
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>Gestion de Series</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="container-nav">
        <nav class="menu">
          <ol>
              <li><a href ="#Series" class="clase1"> Series</a></li>
              <li><a href ="#Opiniones" class="clase2"> Opiniones</a></li>
              <li><a href ="#Estadistica" class="clase3"> Estadisticas</a></li>
              </ol>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
           <article class="manejo-de-series">
              <h2 id="Series">Manejo de Series</h2>
              <p>
              Nombre
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Nombre">
              <br>
              Descripcion
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="Descripcion">
              <br>
              Cantidad de temporadas
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto">
              <br>
              Capitulos por temporada
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="texto">
              </p>
              <p>
              <button type="button"> Agregar/Actualizar </button>
              <button type="button"> Reset </button>
              <button type="button"> Previo </button>
              <button type="button"> Siguiente </button>
              </p>
              <p>
              <a href="https://www.imdb.com/" target="_blank">  <img src="imagenes/IMDb.png" alt="IMDb"> </a>
              </p>
           </article>
           </section>
          </div>
           </header>
```